# xampp not working in windows 7

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am facing error in `xampp`. I did following steps
1: I started the xampp but I found error on `xampp` start
2: Skype port `80` and `443` check not checked
4: Also Skype is quit.
5: On starting xampp again facing same error.
6: After I did changes in `httpd.conf`

```
 #Listen 12.34.56.78:8080       Listen 8080
```

7: And in `httpd.ssl.conf`

```
Listen 4433      <VirtualHost _default_:4433>
```

8: Found same error after these changes
9: `#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so` commenting this `httpd.conf`
Found same error after this change

Answer (score 0):

In skype

click Tools>Options --- untick the box beside 'Start Skype with Windows' --- don't forget to click Save

Skype uses the default port 80 which the apache hold

Comment: Actually this Skype option already implemented but result is same. Do you have any other idea.